# Unicode render issue in browsers

Tags: html, css, unicode, font-family

in my page i need to render some **unicode** symbols from the list bellow.

1. Latin Extended-B
2. Greek and Coptic
3. Cyrillic
4. Herbrew
5. Arabic
6. Syriac
7. NKo
8. Miscellaneous mathematical symbols-A

my code is as per bellow:

```
body
{ 
    font-family:Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif ,Cambria Math, Symbola, Quivira, STIX, Code2000, Code2001, Code2002,Arial Unicode MS; 
}

<div>
    &#x027E1; <br />
    &#x027E2; &#x027E3; &#x027E4; &#x027E5; <br />
    &#x027E6; &#x027E7; &#x027E8; &#x027E9; &#x027EA; &#x027EB; <br />
    &#x027EC; &#x027ED; &#x027EE; &#x027EF;
</div>
```

but some of the symbols are not getting render properly.
instead of the proper symbols **box** type symbols are getting render.
as per bellow.

[image]

i've installed some new fonts (as per list bellow) and restarted the system,

```
Code2000(TrueType)
Code2001(TrueType)
Code2002(TrueType)
arialuni.ttf
```

but still the actual symbols are **not getting render**.

how to get **full support** for **Unicode rendering**.

Comment: Works for me, tested on IE, Chrome, Firefox (newest versions, on Win 7). Which browser(s) were you using? According to the Font Information add-on of Firefox, the fonts actually used are Arial, Cambria Math, and Symbola.

Comment: Windows XP , FF(23.0.1), Chrome(29.0.1547.57 m), IE(8)

Comment: i've tested it in Win 7 also. but some more char i got but not all. can u plz let me know which fonts you have in your system for Unicode support.

Comment: I have all the specific fonts listed in your `font-family` list and a few more. There can however be differences: fonts may exist in different versions under the same name. I suspect that some of the fonts in your system might be broken. Some fonts contain generic placeholder glyphs in some code positions. Note that `serif` refers to whatever happens to be the default serif font in each browser. I suggest that you try first with just `font-family: Aria, Cambria Math, Symbola` to see what happens.

Comment: Oops I meant `sans-serif` (which is in the list), not `serif`, but the point is the same, it maps to *some* sans-serif font according to browser settings.

Comment: What browser setting you are talking about? is it Encoding->Unicode(UTF-8). if it is, then its already there. or else plz let me know what setting i need to change.

Comment: Characters like U+27E2 (which Jukka's browser is getting from Symbola) are just not well-enough supported in commonly-installed fonts to use on the web. If you really *need* to support all these characters, the best you can do is use `@font-face` CSS to embed a font that supports them all.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add this into your  tags

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, all browsers support `@font-face` for loading webfonts and can support any character within those fonts. As such, you should be able to display any character in any browser if you make sure you provide access to a webfont with support for those characters.

To avoid using giant fonts just to support a few special characters, you can create your own fonts with tools like the **[Icomoon App](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)**.

I used the Icomoon App to create the **[Emoji emoticon font](https://github.com/jslegers/emoji-icon-font)** as well as for creating custom icon fonts on a per project basis.

For more info on the use or creation of icon fonts (or other webfonts), see **[Create webfont with Unicode Supplementary Multilingual Plane symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824628/create-webfont-with-unicode-supplementary-multilingual-plane-symbols/27410391#27410391)**

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for the UTF, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp